# Redactor splitting nested <a> tags

Tags: redactor

I have a little issue with Redactor. Whenever I have a link within a link:

```
<a href="#">main link <a href="#">link within link</a> </a>
```

Redactor automatically modifies it to this:

```
<a href="#">main link</a> <a href="#">link within link</a>
```

Is there a way to stop this auto-modification?

Comment: Redactor, Craft's rich text editor, actually does this, not the "template engine" (Twig). Is that what you mean?

Comment: As this is a Twig related question (or possibly, Redactor, as per @RitterKnight's comment) I think this question is absolutely relevant and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff: Agreed, great catch. Voting to "leave open", and I'll edit the question to better reflect Redactor's role.

Answer (score 6):

The template engine ([Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)) doesn't do anything like that – my guess is that the links only *appear* to render like your second example, because you're looking at the markup in your browser's dev tools, and modern browsers (e.g. Chrome) do a pretty good job of rendering invalid HTML.

Take a look at the raw source code (i.e. "View source" in your browser), and I suspect the actual rendered HTML will look exactly like your first example.

In any case, nesting `<a>` tags is not allowed and a very bad idea – so I'd recommend not doing it all :)

Comment: If you ignore the phrase "template engine" , I think what he's asking is not about Twig but actually Redactor.    If you paste the snippet mentioned into source code mode, Redactor will do exactly as he mentions. I can see how some users might think that's part of the the "template engine."

Comment: @RitterKnight You might be right, and you should add an additional answer - if the OP is talking about Redactor, it might be that turning off the "Purify HTML?" option for the Rich Text field will do the trick. Still a bad idea, though :)

Answer (score 5):

Redactor is, very sensibly, correcting your invalid html. **You can't have links inside links**, the spec does not allow it: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Even if Redactor didn't do this, the browser will treat your invalid html as invalid and take a best guess at reconstructing it to form valid html; probably with varying results.